# MS Access if statement on click event

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Ms Access forms and I have created an on click event that locates a folder location but now I want to locate the folder location based on different criteria but when I add the if statement it expects a sub,function or property. Below is some demo code. I really hope someone can explain what is missing?

```
    Private Sub Open_Email_Click()
    Dim stAppName As String
    Dim stAppNameA As String
    Dim stAppNameB As String
    stAppName  = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\DEMO\TEST\" & Me.Office & " DEMO\B " & Me.BC & " " & Me.UC & "\"
    stAppNameA = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\DEMO\TEST\" & Me.Office & " DEMO\A\B " & Me.BC & " " & Me.UC & "\"
    stAppNameB = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\DEMO\TEST\" & Me.Office & " DEMO\B\B " & Me.BC & " " & Me.UC & "\"

    If (Me.BC = "60") And Me.UC Like "REF123*" Then stAppNameA
    ElseIf (Me.BC = "60") And Not Me.UC Like "REF123*" Then stAppNameB
    Else: stAppName
    End If

Call Shell(stAppName, 1) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the logic of your function could be reduced to the following, which may be more readable with fewer repeating expressions:

```
Private Sub Open_Email_Click()
    Dim strTmp As String

    If Me.BC = "60" Then
        If Me.UC Like "REF123*" Then
            strTmp = " DEMO\A\B "
        Else
            strTmp = " DEMO\B\B "
        End If
    Else
        strTmp = " DEMO\B "
    End If
    Call Shell("C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\DEMO\TEST\" & Me.Office & strTmp & Me.BC & " " & Me.UC & "\", 1)
End Sub
```

Alternatively, using a `Select Case` statement:

```
Private Sub Open_Email_Click()
    Dim strTmp As String

    Select Case True
        Case Me.BC <> "60"
            strTmp = " DEMO\B "
        Case Me.UC Like "REF123*"
            strTmp = " DEMO\A\B "
        Case Else
            strTmp = " DEMO\B\B "
    End Select
    Call Shell("C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\DEMO\TEST\" & Me.Office & strTmp & Me.BC & " " & Me.UC & "\", 1)
End Sub
```

To test the resulting path, change:

```
Call Shell("C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\DEMO\TEST\" & Me.Office & strTmp & Me.BC & " " & Me.UC & "\", 1)
```

To:

```
Debug.Print "C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\DEMO\TEST\" & Me.Office & strTmp & Me.BC & " " & Me.UC & "\"
```

Comment: Lee this is a much cleaner way, I have tried to use this but it is not opening to the file path to the new location only to DEMO\B\B. also in your code you have BD which I think is a typo where it should be BC.

Comment: @New2Programming Good spot! I have now corrected the `BD` typo.

Comment: @New2Programming With the typo fixed, is the code now operating successfully?

Comment: I am not getting an error now but the folder location is not opening to the correct location and only to my documents instead of the actual folder, I have location names but it is like something is missing. Can I print out the location name in the console to see what location the event is trying to find?

Comment: @New2Programming Sure thing - I have updated my answer above to show you how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Lee that works perfectly and resolves the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your `If` block is just a bit messy in terms of where you have newlines, and continuation characters (:). Try reformatting your code like this:

```
    If (Me.BC = "60") And Me.UC Like "REF123*" Then 
        stAppName =stAppNameA
    ElseIf (Me.BC = "60") And Not Me.UC Like "REF123*" Then 
        stAppName = stAppNameB
    Else 
        stAppName =stAppName
    End If

    Call Shell(stAppName, 1)
```